# How to get the dragged y distance for a reclycler view when on scroll state changed?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onscrolllistener

for a recycler view,onScrollStateChanged,when new state become SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING,how to get the dragged y distance?

Answer (score 0):

In OnScrollListener you can also override

`public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)`

Then you can use a member variable to keep track of the overall dy;

ex:

```
int mScrollDy = 0;
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
    mScrollDy += dy;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.in fact i want the dragged distance, means how long the finger dragged(moved) down.I want to perform the action after the recycler view reaches it's  top end.